# Logging not working in Spring Boot (Gradle)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons-logging

I have an interceptor which I'm trying to use to log:

```
package com.noxgroup.nitro.security;
...
```

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

```
@Component
public class SecurityInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handlingObject) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Interceptor firing...");
    }
}
```

So I configured application.properties as such:

```
debug=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.com.noxgroup.nitro=DEBUG
logging.level.com.noxgroup.nitro.security=DEBUG
```

But no suck luck. Nothing appearing in the console. `System.out.println` does work though.

**Note:** I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` which I'm under the impression has an implementation of Apache Commons Logging within it...

**Edit:** I can log `info`, but `debug` isn't logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to set the level to DEBUG for your own package, i.e.

```
logging.level.com.noxgroup.nitro.security=DEBUG
```

To run every log in DEBUG mode, you can also try

```
logging.level.=DEBUG
```

Comment: Good that you pointed that out - `logging.level.=DEBUG` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Works perfectly in all my maven projects. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out three-fold:

1. Correctly, as @Sanjay suggested, I needed to specify the actual package, and not assume that a higher level package will filter down. This allowed me to log level `info` but not  level `debug`
2. I wasn't actually using application.properties. I had a Spring `@Configuration` class that was loading a properties file, *on-the-fly*. It actually needs to be in the spring detected application.properties
3. I was using JULI, where as SLF4J is actually implemented with Logback in Spring Boot.